# Laravel - Utilizar JOIN + COUNT

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-8

Tenho duas tabelas, umas de usuários (users) e outra de empresas (companies). Eu preciso selecionar os dados de cada empresa e saber a quantidade de usuários por empresa.

Esse select no mysql funciona da forma que preciso:

```
SELECT companies.id as id, companies.name as name, companies.phone as phone, COUNT(*) as qtdUsers
FROM users
INNER JOIN companies 
ON users.company_id = companies.id 
GROUP BY company_id
ORDER BY qtdUsers DESC;
```

No laravel, ele ficou da seguinte forma:

```
$teste = DB::table('users')
        ->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'users.company_id')
        ->select('companies.id as id', 'companies.name as name', 'companies.phone as phone', DB::raw('count(*) as qtdUsers'))
        ->groupBy('users.company_id')
        ->orderBy('qtdUsers', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Porém está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
lluminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'proj01_db.companies.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `companies`.`id` as `id`, `companies`.`name` as `name`, `companies`.`phone` as `phone`, count(*) as qtdUsers from `users` inner join `companies` on `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id` group by `users`.`company_id` order by `qtdUsers` desc)
```

Quando coloco o 'companies.id' no groupBy, é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'proj01_db.companies.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `companies`.`id` as `id`, `companies`.`name` as `name`, `companies`.`phone` as `phone`, count(*) as qtdUsers from `users` inner join `companies` on `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id` group by `companies`.`id` order by `qtdUsers` desc)
```

Alguém sabe como resolver? Obrigada desde já.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-q-answersid-isnt-in-group-by

Answer (score 0):

Enconte o arquivo `config/database.php` procure o campo `'strict'` e defina ele como false.

```
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => false
]
```